# Переключатель HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать переключатель контента по клику на соответствующую вкладку (Доставка/Оплата)?
Что бы под переключателем менялся контент (display:block/none)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду признателен за помощь

Answer (score 2):

Набросок на коленке одного их вариантов представлен ниже. Осталось стилизовать `input` под ваши потребности. А в будущем старайтесь гуглить самостоятельно, а тут просить помощь в решении конкретно того, что уже не получилось.

```js
var dostavka = document.getElementById('dostavka'),
    oplata = document.getElementById('oplata'),
    tab1 = document.querySelector('.tab1'),
    tab2 = document.querySelector('.tab2'),
    input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
  input[i].onchange = function() {
    if (dostavka.checked) {
      tab1.style.display = 'block';
      tab2.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (oplata.checked) {
      tab1.style.display = 'none';
      tab2.style.display = 'block';
    };
  };
};
```

```css
.tab1 {  display: block;}
.tab2 {  display: none;}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="dostavka" name="checker" checked />
<input type="radio" id="oplata" name="checker" />
<div class="tab1">11111</div>
<div class="tab2">22222</div>
```

Comment: @alex мерси, fixed

Answer (score 1):

Это стандартное поведение, обычно называемое табами. Можно воспользоваться готовыми решениями (например, [jQueryUI tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)) или написать что-то самостоятельно. Если хочется на выходе получить как можно более гибкий и простой к изменениям код, лучше всего как можно меньше данных зашивать в код.

Я подготовил небольшой пример, иллюстрирующий подход с выненсением логики представления в слой HTML. Чтобы код получился более лаконичным, можно воспользоваться какими-нибудь библиотеками для работы с DOM (jQuery, Sizzle, atomjs, etc).

```js
var toArray = function(nodes) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);
  },

  ACTIVE_CSS_SELECTOR = 'active',

  tabSwitchers = toArray(document.querySelectorAll('button[data-tab]')),

  activateTab = function(name) {
    var tabs = toArray(document.querySelectorAll('.tab[data-tab]'));

    tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
      tab.dataset.tab === name ?
        tab.classList.add(ACTIVE_CSS_SELECTOR) : tab.classList.remove(ACTIVE_CSS_SELECTOR);
    });
  },

  tabSwitchClickHandler = function(event) {
    activateTab(event.target.dataset.tab);
  };

tabSwitchers.forEach(function(button) {
  button.onclick = tabSwitchClickHandler;
});
```

```css
.tab {
  display: none;
}

.tab.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button data-tab='payment'>Payment</button>
<button data-tab='delivery'>Delivery</button>

<div class='tabs container'>
  <div class="tab active" data-tab='payment'>Payment tab content</div>
  <div class="tab" data-tab='delivery'>Delivery tab content</div>
</div>
```

На [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rtusbzs/).

Answer (score 1):

Вашу задачу можно решить на css

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b-tabs {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

[id^=tab-] {
  display: none;
}

[id^=tab-] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #E1D9D4;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

[id^=tab-] + label:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

[id^=tab-] + label:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

[id^=tab-] + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

[id^=tab-]:checked + label:before {
  bottom: 0;
  background: #00f;
  height: 100%;
}

[id^=tab-]:checked + label > span {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

[id^=tab-] + label ~ [id^=tab-content-] {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#tab-1:checked + label ~ #tab-content-1,
#tab-2:checked + label ~ #tab-content-2 {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-tabs">
  <input type="radio" name="t" id="tab-1" checked />
  <label for="tab-1"><span>Доставка</span></label>

  <input type="radio" name="t" id="tab-2" />
  <label for="tab-2"><span>Оплата</span></label>

  <div id="tab-content-1">
    b-tab-content 1
  </div>
  <div id="tab-content-2">
    b-tab-content 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение, реализовал вот  так (jQuerry положил в body) http://www.fixcenter.com.ua/test/